# How to use media queries in an effective way?

Tags: css, media

Now, I understand how "breakpoints" work - when the browser window reaches a certain width, the element within the queries changes. Now, here is my question:

If I start designing a website, and start adding styles for how I want to look on a mobile device, when the design is finished and I want to expand on it, what's the effective way on doing it? 
At the moment, all that I can think of is adding a queries with a higher min-width breakpoint, and then paste the CSS from the code that I already made and start making changes respectively, within the queries. I have a strong feeling that this is not the correct way of doing things, so this is why I am asking for help. Thanks!

Comment: I do always start mine like this:
- Markup
-  at media screen and (min-width : 280px)
Then i try to finish the whole mobile layout, not caring about pads nad desktop at this point. When i am done with this, the next step is:
/*-breakpoint--*/
    @media screen and (min-width : 768px)
Then i finish the desktop version, and if need be add some fixes for pads, pads do not support as many thing as desktops do, f.e. fixed backgrounds. I never use the max width queries.
You can work it in other ways, but the above is the easiest mobile first approach to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the correct approach when it comes to making a design and thinking mobile first.  Now what you need to do is think of how it will be when you resize it to large device widths.

There are a lot of things you can look into, many people could suggest you to look at frameworks such as Bootstrap just to understand how they use media queries to achieve many things. My advice is to use as little media queries as you can. Try to support at least two device widths: mobile/tablets and desktop. Since mobile/desktop can be interchangeable and new devices are always coming out, a consistent design is best. However you can safely support mobile/tablet/desktop if you take the time to do so properly.

Now, I will try to keep it very simple for you and introduce the most basic way to do media queries right and expand from there.

Let's begin with the most important yet simplest building block of responsive web design: a container element. This container element is to be used for the content in your website, the content is for you to choose to imagine upon, since these containers will need to expand from device width to device with accordingly.

Navigation bar example:

```
.navigation-bar-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Check the above code its so simple and straight forward, what does it do? I can imagine it will hold all the elements within a navigation bar. It can certainly be used in more than just that way, but for now all we care about its a navigation bar.

It's minimum width is `320px`, because the smallest screen you need to support may be `320px` wide (iPhone anyone) so there is no need to shrink your element below that.

Max width is interesting. Currently the nav bar's max width is 100% because I said it is... **no**, that does not make any sense. Why is it 100%? It is because I want to make it always expand to the full width of the screen, regardless of the screen width. That is it's default behavior.

Now try and think of what will happen to your navigation bar's width when you are in a different screen sizes, such as mobile devices. What will happen with the elements, will they shrink with your container? Will they even fit when the screen size is too small? **Enter media queries**.

- Full desktop widths: approximately `769px` or above... this is subject to change of course.

The max width is 100% and width 100% means it will adjust to whatever the screen size is. Default behavior doing its thing, yes!

- Tablets: approximately `421px` to `768px`... this is subject to change of course

If your elements will not fit into all tablet sizes and make your navigation bar look weird, yes try it throw some divs and stuff in it and shrink it, then what do we do? It is time to make them fit by using the good old media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .navigation-bar-container { 
        display: none;
    }

    .sliding-navbar-container {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 320px;
    }
}
```

Yes I did not make them fit at all. I swapped the good old `navigation-bar-container` width a different one. Classic example of what is good and safe when using media queries. Instead of breaking your head over how to fit these elements, spare no hesitation my friend, just swap your navigation bar for another that will work on smaller devices in there.

Note how the new navigation bar actually accounts for its width `320px`, it will sit absolutely positioned to the top and left of the screen, doing a good job there. How to make it slide in and out, pop up, look neat is another question entirely! Don't ask unless you are curious... back to media queries!

However if we are speaking of an element which will change, let's say it always occupies 100 percent of your screen width, and then shrink to occupy half of the screen width for tablet/landscape phone devices only, then you may want to use a media query like so:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 421px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

Very small and simple change. Max width is interesting because it controls your inner width, which is by default set to 100%. This change will force your element to adjust to 50% of the screen width while still resizing to adjust to 100% of the new element width. It could also be a good idea to make it `max-width: 50vw` since it will adjust to the *viewport width* instead, thus making it responsive even when dealing with widely different viewports.

And so, we come to our conclusion **TLDR**:

- Use as little media query sizes as you need, because if you need a lot then you are doing it wrong, seriously!
- If you need a lot, cannot avoid it, then get to know [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), let other people worry about the media query nightmares.
- Think in *containers*, your elements will sit and move around in them. Think of how these containers will flow from desktop to mobile and vice versa. Putting thought behind this is crucial as it is the source of your responsive behavior and should be the focus of your media queries.
- Although not covered here, you can easily look at media queries and font/image examples. Responsive fonts and images are a crucial part of your content and they as such should be accounted for with media queries. Background image changes, better readability depending on the device you are on, all of that matters and can be simplified via media queries.
- I put this last here because **IT MATTERS A LOT** use [SASS/SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/) and save yourself a ton of trouble when working with media queries (and everything CSS). Look into mixins, variables, partials which you can use along media queries. You will love it if you didn't know about it and start using it now.
- Need more? Fine enjoy [Google's responsive web design fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/fundamentals/?hl=en)

Good luck!!!