# How to reduce the number of @media CSS codes?

Tags: html, css

My CSS is working  but how do I reduce the number of @media CSS codes (I feel some are unnecessary)?

```css
.spandemo {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 42%;
}


}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .spandemo {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 1%;
  }
}
.column {
  width: 98%;
  float: right;
}

}
.column img {
  max-height: 129px;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 90%;
    float: right;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column img {
    max-height: 129px;
    height: 70%;
    width: 90%;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .column img {
    max-height: 372px;
    height: 70%;
    width: 90%;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img class="responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/left/200/300" style="width:50%" border="1" />
    <img class="responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/right/200/300" style="float:right; width:50%" border="1" />
    <span style="float:left;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Before</span>
    <span class="spandemo" style="float:left;">&nbsp;&nbsp;After</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a follow up question to what I asked here: [CSS working for mobile view but not wide screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77067044/css-working-for-mobile-view-but-not-wide-screens#77067985)

I added all the @media CSS codes to get the desired effects but I think some are unnecessary if used in the correct order. Please let me know what can be removed or edited.
At [How to use media queries in an effective way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485405/how-to-use-media-queries-in-an-effective-way) it tells us to put all the @media queries together but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You have the same media query target value (i.e. `max-width: 600px`) repeated multiple times, which can all be consolidated to one block. That said, there are a few different ways to organize your media queries (e.g. by target query sizes vs by each CSS selector, etc), and it generally isn't a big performance concern to have multiple media queries if it's your concern.

Answer (score 0):

A few tips:

1.) You don't need to repeat the exact same `@media` query multiple times, you can put multiple CSS rules inside a single query.

2.) When the `@media` query is triggered, it just adds those styles to the rules that are already in place.  So, for example, if an element has `float: right;` you don't need to add `float: right;` to the same element inside the `@media` query.

3.) In general it's a good idea to write your CSS in a way so that no `@media` queries are needed at all for the smallest screen size.  As the screen size gets larger add more `@media` queries to override the previous styles.  This means you should probably only use `@media screen and (min-width: ____)` values and not ones that target `max-width`.  Especially important: don't use **both `min-width` and `max-width` queries as this will get very confusing for you since they might overlap

Below is just a simple cleanup that removes the duplication I mentioned in those first 2 tips.  I have not gone through and figured out how to implement #3 since you would probably know better than me for what you want here.

```css
.spandemo {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 42%;
}

.column {
  width: 98%;
  float: right;
}

.column img {
  max-height: 129px;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .spandemo {
    padding-left: 1%;
  }
  
  .column {
    width: 90%;
  }

  .column img {
    height: 70%;
    width: 90%;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .column img {
    max-height: 372px;
    height: 70%;
    width: 90%;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img class="responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/left/200/300" style="width:50%" border="1" />
    <img class="responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/right/200/300" style="float:right; width:50%" border="1" />
    <span style="float:left;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Before</span>
    <span class="spandemo" style="float:left;">&nbsp;&nbsp;After</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am able to use one  
````@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {  
which makes all the widescreens obey it but above it, I have to use the  
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {  
for each "spandemo" div, "column" div as well as the "column img"